# Is it possible to check the reachability of another device before sending message?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I know we can send a message from within an iPhone app, but I want to check the reachability of my friend's device from his contact info or from any detail of that device before sending the message. Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible, unless your app can tell a server that it is online, like how WhatsApp does it.